# JMeter Space between text in parameters replaced with '+'

Tags: jmeter

I'm new to JMeter. Please help me on this. How to pass parameter values with space between the two strings say

Parameter example:

`x="My New Place"`

When i use the value as is, it gets replaced with `+` in request as `x=My+New+Place`

how to overcome this issue.

Comment: Where are you using the parameter value? Are spaces allowed there? There could be an `encode` checkbox somewhere you might be able to uncheck.

Comment: I did uncheck the encode option. But still no luck. I just copied the request params as is and when i pass it, replaces with "+" for space

Comment: Go you speak about GET or POST parameters ?

Answer (score 2):

You might have to uncheck the `Encode` for the parameter to remove `+`.

In the `Get` method, I think it would throw URI syntax exception if there is no `+`

**EDIT:**

Remove the parameters & Use `Body Data` section. add `x=My New Place`.

`x=My New Place` will be sent w/o `+`

Comment: i did uncheck the Encode option for parameter but no luck. And by the way it's a `post` method

Answer (score 0):

I found that though i check or uncheck the `Encode` the request goes with `+` for space. In `view results tree`, i saw the request replaces space with `+` under `Request` tab and could see no HTML under `Response Data`. But what i found interesting in `Response Data` tab is it shows `Failed to parse HTML: null`. When i switch it to `text` or `document` i could see the response data. There is this bug actually which cleared all my doubts. Thanks to all for your time and effort.

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54166